# How do I get the values of the RecordSource in an Access combobox

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in Access with a combobox on it.

The combobox gets the displayed values through an SQL select statement by
means of the `RowSource` property which is set to something like
`select description, id_of_table, col_foo from tblTable`

Since I usually need the selected id_of_table, the property `BoundColumn` is set to 2. So, I can access this value (for example in an AfterUpdate Event) like
`var_id_of_table = me.cboWhatever`
which works with no problems.

Now, at times, I do not only need id_of_table but also the value of `col_foo`. So, the question is, how would I go about getting this desired value. I thought I could get it by
something like
`var_foo = me.cboWhatever("col_foo")`
but it didn't work.

I'd appreciate any input on this matter.

Thanks / Rene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
var_foo = me.cboWhatever.column(n)
```

Where *n* is the column number starting from 0.

Comment: Thanks Remou for your help which I appreciate very much.